# Product Reference inside a Product Reference?

Tags: commerce, entities

In my attempt to solve a "variation can update second variation" issue, I am wondering if a Product reference can go inside another Product Reference?

So that the 'Variation' itself has a product reference inline form to another type of variation? ( I have tried and nothing shows up).

The idea is that loading 1 variation will then load the referenced product variations therein and combine the 2 to create the final price.

(This is a case where the 2nd variations price is based on what is selected in the 1st variation.)

Comment: Are you trying for bundling several product together ?

Comment: no, i dont think so. Im trying a case where there are beds, and bed covers. So the beds have a size of Twin, Queen etc. And THEN the covers price should change when a different size bed is selected.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out by using taxonomy terms (categories in commerce kickstart), and then yes, indeed, make a product for each combination. (ive heard bulk product creation can do this, and incase you are dealing with a customer input size (how many inches long do you want it), then check out custom line items and Pricing rules.

Thread on drupal commerce > http://www.drupalcommerce.org/questions/7894/adjust-variation-price-based-next-variation#comment-7566